# Meaning of a measure

Tags: measure-theory

Supose we have a measure $\mu$ on a measure space $(X,\mathcal{A})$ and a measurable function $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

What is the meaning of the measure $\nu=f\,d\mu$ (that is, what is $\nu(B)$ in termos of $f$ and $\mu$)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may call $\nu$ the $\mu$-absolutely-continuous measure which has $f$ for its [Radon-Nikodym derivative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_theorem#Radon.E2.80.93Nikodym_derivative).